# How to allocate memory based on the number of elements in an STL list?

Tags: c++, stl, allocator

There is an option to provide a custom allocator for STL containers. However, I cannot find an implementation that can increase the memory pool block size once the pool runs out of space. How can an STL allocator read the size of the list container and self-growing the block size?

For example, the block size starts with 1, 2, 4 and so on, and then when there are 1, 3, 7 nodes inside the container, the blocks size grows right after the next insertion occurs.

Comment: Can you make the purpose for this need a bit more clearer? I understand that you want to know from your allocator how much elements there are in the list you allocate for. You can achieve that by simple counting the number of allocations-deallocations from your allocator. However, how would that help you?

Comment: Not sure if this link can help you, [Improving Performance with Custom Pool Allocator](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/improving-performance-with-custom-pool-a/184406243)

Comment: What would happen if you splice nodes from one list to another?

Comment: @MSalters They will share the same memory pool, so both lists should deallocate if neither of them are not (or won't be) operating.

Answer (score 1):

The standard containers use the supplied allocator (call its member functions) to allocate memory they need.   The reverse doesn't happen - there is nothing in the allocator interface, as specified by the standard, that allows it to be given information about what container is using it.   Which means that no custom allocator - as long as it has the same interface as required in the standard - has the means of interrogating the container size.

To do what you want, you would need a special purpose allocator with a different interface than standard allocators, and a custom container (e.g. replacement for `std::list`) that knows how to communicate with that special-purpose allocator.     Trying to get your custom allocator to work with a standard container, or your custom container to work with a standard allocator, would not work well - the interfaces would be incompatible.

Also, the behaviour you describe (allocation doubling every time) is specific to your implementation of the standard library.  Although that allocation strategy is somewhat common, it is not required by the standard.   Other implementations are permitted - and some do - use different allocation strategies.

In the end, it would probably be easier to calculate/estimate an upper bound for the size of your containers, use that to work out how much memory your program needs to run, and install at least that amount of memory.

Answer (score 1):

An allocator usually doesn't depend on the container type which is its client — that would be a circular dependency. The cycle would need to be resolved by some sort of incomplete class interface or type erasure.

For example, with incomplete class pointers:

```
struct my_pool;

template< typename t >
struct my_allocator {
    my_pool * pool;
    // allocate, deallocate, etc.
};

struct my_pool {
    std::list< foo, my_allocator< foo > > const * client;
};

std::list< foo, my_allocator< foo > > things;
my_pool.client = & things;
```

In this case, `my_pool` depends on `std::list<…, my_allocator>` depends on `my_allocator<std::__list_node>` depends on `my_pool`, but the cycle is OK because several dependencies are only pointers.

For example, with `std::function` type erasure:

```
struct my_pool {
    std::function< std::size_t() > client_size;
};

std::list< foo, my_allocator< foo > > things;
my_pool.client_size = [&]{ return things.size(); };
```

This pool doesn't even need to know the container type.

But, in either case, this doesn't seem like particularly good design. The pool cannot be shared by other containers, at least not equally.

Comment: The problem with this is that it is the CONTAINER which decides the allocation strategy (how much memory is requested from the allocator), not the allocator.   If the allocator was to allocate less memory than the container has requested, then the container would exhibit undefined behaviour when it attempts to use the memory it requested, but that the allocator did not provide.

Comment: @Peter The question is unclear, but to me it looks like the allocator decides how to expand the pool on the basis of the size of a particular container. In any case, as long as the allocator's `allocate` method works as required, everything is fine.

Comment: yes the OP has incorrectly assumed it is the allocator that determines the allocation strategy.    But if the allocator `allocate()` returns a different (particularly a smaller) size than requested, the container receives no information indicating that.   In other words, `allocate()` is required to either return at least the amount requested or fail (e.g. the standard allocators throw).

Comment: @Peter We both might be reading to much into the question. And we're reading it differently.

Comment: Maybe.  My take is that the OP expects to be able to supply an allocator to a standard container that changes what strategy is used to allocate memory.   Which is not possible, since the container determines the allocation strategy, not the allocator.   The allocator just services requests for memory (from whatever source of memory it manages).   The container makes those requests.  The allocation strategy is the means that the container decides what requests to make.

Comment: @Peter I expect that I can supply an allocator to an STL list that can make the memory pool block size on demand.

Comment: @Kevin Dong -  thanks - that confirmed my understanding.

Comment: @Peter I dunno, seems to confirm my understanding as well. You're supposing that "pool block size" refers to allocations *within* the pool, I'm presuming that it refers to blocks from the free store, from which the pool allocates.